# Sending Application to background on iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is it possible to send the application to background programmatically on iPhone?

Comment: I am still wondering how this is not possible. I would love to have apps that let me move them to background or even exit them without the need of any button!

Answer (score 3):

Under iOS 4.0, your app will be put in the background if another app enters the foreground, and there are enough resources to keep your app in the background.  You could send a URL to Safari, or another app that has registered for a handler, and hope that there's enough memory (etc.) that the OS puts your app in the background after it starts Safari (or whatever app handled the URL).  If you are lucky (which typically happens fairly often), you will have sent your app programmatically to the background.

Of course, whether your app runs in the background, or is just suspended, depends on other things (which you have to register with iOS 4.x for).

Comment: The word "background" means something very specific on iOS and it is not as you describe it. What you mean is "inactive." An inactive app is still running. A background app is not running. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does allow apps to exit (kill themselves) programmatically. But it's meant only as a last resort for when something bad happens from which your app cannot recover.

On all other occasions, apps are expected to stay in the foreground and running until either the user presses the home button or the app opens another app, with the users consent.

Actually you don't want to kill the app, however moving it to the background and returning to the home screen would leave a very similar impression. That's why I don't think Apple would approve it and consequently doesn't offer, as far as I know, any means to move an app to the background programmatically without opening another app.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. Only iOS can put your application in the background.

Note that there's a lot of confusion between "background" and "inactive". An inactive application is one that is not displayed on the GUI but is still running.

Technically an application in the background isn't running; it's dormant. Depending on the mode used, a background applications can receive signals and "wake up." See Background Modes for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22

But a background application can also get terminated at any point without warning. As a matter of fact I always treat a background application as terminated. Therefore you should always clean up your application before you enter the background, and re-initialize it when you enter the foreground.

This is a must-read on this topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 0):

check out these post

[local notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234279/local-notifications)

[iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events)