# What are the criteria for determining apps with a UIBackgroundMode acceptance?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have a requirement to develop an app that is capable of receiving pushed information from a server - which as its not possible to intercept SMSs or apple push notifications would probably have to be implemented as a poll and see what's there or similar type of thing. 
However of course such a thing isn't possible if the app isn't executing in the background.

The app couldn't be considered to be musical or voip related, however its possible that it could be considered to be gps related as the pushed information would be displayed to the user based on certain triggers, and one of those triggers could be location.

Would this app with a UIBackgroundMode of gps submitted to the app store stand a good chance of being accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been trying to do the same thing and here is what i found
[iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events)
(top answer: update 2)
shows a method that should be ok, meaning your app wont be rejected for using it.  the guy who posted it said it should be ok and i have asked other members who said the same (i have not verified this myself).
here is my implementation of that post
[local notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234279/local-notifications)

Comment: theres alot of good info on that first link, the only thing is that i know ios5 might have changed a few things, but my simulator and device are on 5 and code works on them

Comment: Thanks for that link, looks useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a hack for your requirements.

iOS provides a facility whereas your application is suspended but your socket is still monitored. If there's any incoming traffic on the socket, the app is woken up and handed back the control of the socket.

[Advanced App Tricks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

Look under the heading, "Tips for Developing a VoIP App"

Comment: Thanks for that link. However my application is not, and could not be considered an VoIP app, therefore I would be concerned if it had a UIBackgroundMode of VoIP, but wasn't actually a real VoiP app it would be rejected. Can you or anybody comment on this?